# Textarea text does not allow to change text after complete the MaxLength

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem to alter the text in textarea.
I set my TextArea MaxLength="250". After reach the MaxLength of 250 character in textarea now I want to change some selected character from the length of 250 characters in textarea. But textarea not allow me to alter the text.

When length is lessthan 250 character then I alter the text. 
Please help

Comment: because entering a new char would push the length past the limit.

Comment: How can I alter the text? I am stuck and cannot find any solution.

Comment: Before updating the value, change the `maxLength` property and once value is `updated`, re-assign the `length`..

Comment: @Rayon can you please send me sample of code?

Answer (score 1):

Before updating the value, change the `maxlength` property as per your need and once value is updated, re-assign the `maxlength`

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var elem = $('#ta');
  var maxLen = elem.attr('maxlength');
  elem.attr('maxlength', 10).val('Crayon').attr('maxlength', maxLen);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="ta" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="5">Rayon</textarea>
<button type="button" id="btn">Change the text</button>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fmh900a0/1/)

Comment: Please try to fix on IE browsers. It is not working in IE with compabality view mode. My client is using only IE.

Comment: I am try to use IE 9 and IE 10 compability view mode. In IE 9 Max Length is more than enter in current length and in IE 10 compability view mode feddle demo is not display any result.

Comment: @FarrukhShahid the Rayon is not write the project for you. If you dont know how to programming all that you are not on the correct position at the first place.

Comment: @Aristos can you please let me know the correct solution?

Comment: @FarrukhShahid – `maxlength` is supported since `IE > 9`

Comment: $('#id')keyup(function () {
            var limit = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
            var text = $(this).val();
            var chars = text.length + 1;
            if (chars > limit) {
                var new_text = text.substr(0, limit - 1);
                $(this).val(new_text);
            }
        });
this is some sample which I want. But some problem is when press enter to create new line and maxlength of textarea achieve then I am not able to alter the selected textarea and curser is blinking at the end also after pressing the arrow keys cursor move at the end

Comment: @FarrukhShahid – The reason of cursor blinking at end is _value being updated.._